# How to use a variable as a partial path name with Get-Content?

Tags: powershell

How can I use the UNC path $data variable as part of my Get-Content path?

```
$data = "\\MyServer\MyShare"
$OU = Get-Content $data + "ou.txt"
$OU
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$data = "\\MyServer\MyShare"
$OU = Get-Content ( JOIN-PATH $data  "ou.txt" )
```